# What Linux desktop environments support HiDPI displays?

Tags: desktop-environment, elementary-os

I'm currently running ElementaryOS, whose default desktop shell is a bit lacking in features; however, it renders properly on a HiDPI Retina display, which is a nice feature.

I'm looking to switch over to something a bit more customizable, but HiDPI support is a must for me; which desktop environments *currently* support HiDPI displays natively (or with a very small amount of tweaking)? Which ones have HiDPI support in the pipeline and close to release?

Comment: gnome does support that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the popular linux desktop environments have HiDPI support. `Gnome`, `KDE`, `Xfce`, `Cinnamon` all four most popular linux desktop have the HiDPI support.

`Cinnamon` currently have the best support of HiDPI displays. It automatically recognizes a HiDPI display

Setting up HiDPI support in `gnome` needs some works at terminal (No automatic detection till now). But customizability wise `gnome` is best. As `gnome tweak tools` gives a lot of customizability and it is also easier to customize.

Comment: Thanks! Could you describe (or post a link) to a resource which shows you how to customize GNOME so that it works with HiDPI?

Comment: In `gnome` desktop from the terminal you need to change the `interface scaling factor` to 2 (from default 1). You can do it graphically to using `gnome tweak tools` too. Here is a link : http://askubuntu.com/questions/668749/how-to-set-up-gnome-interface-for-hidpi-screen